# Having Javascript happen when someone clicks but then drags off the button

Tags: javascript, css, html, button

I have made buttons using s that have style changes when you onMouseOver, onMouseOut, onMouseDown, and onMouseUp, but if someone clicks and then drags off the button the button stays in the onMouseDown state. I tried using different onDrag states but that is not the way to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: so detecting onMouseDown, then onMouseOut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onMouseOut`.

`onMouseDown` would turn a boolean flag on, and `onMouseOut` and `onMouseUp` would turn it off.

For example, the `onMouseDown` code would be something like `beingClicked = true`, and `onMouseOut` and `onMouseUp` would be `beingClicked = false`.

Alternatively, you could just call `onMouseUp()` in your `onMouseOut` listener.

Comment: +1 Or, you could listen for `onMouseMove` and clear the flag if the `event.target` isn't the button.